# Using countif with multiple criteria to gather data from one week ago

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Want to be able to count how many "corrective" and "1st" from a week ago in excel. This is what I have so far but having issues adding the week ago in the criteria. The data for the dates are in a separate column.

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!S438:S630, "*1st*", Data!J438:J630, "*Corrective*")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see data from a week ago exactly try using TODAY()-7, note that this function is pretty resource intensive if you want to use it on-mass:

Try this by adding it to your formula

```
=COUNTIFS(Data![date_range],"="&TODAY()-7)
```

you can change the = for a <= if you want data from week ago or older